# TypeORM Select Column from relation without using QueryBuilder

Tags: javascript, typeorm

**If anyway to select columns from relation without using querybuilder ???**
This is my current query:

```
  const areas = await this.areaRepository.find({
                            where: { ...isActive },
                            relations: ["division"],
                        });
```

Output :

```
{
        "id": 1,
        "version": 9,
        "isActive": 1,
        "createdBy": null,
        "updatedBy": 1,
        "createAt": "2022-04-18T15:42:12.000Z",
        "updatedAt": "2022-09-23T11:04:53.000Z",
        "name": "Dhaka",
        "division": {
          "id": 3,
          "version": 1,
          "isActive": 1,
          "createdBy": null,
          "updatedBy": null,
          "createAt": "2022-04-18T15:42:00.000Z",
          "updatedAt": "2022-04-18T15:42:00.000Z",
          "name": "Dhaka"
        }
      },
```

But is there anything like:

```
const areas = await this.areaRepository.find({
                    select: ['id','division.id division_id']
                    where: { ...isActive },
                    relations: ["division"],
                });
```

And the output will be:

```
{
   "id": 1,
   "division_id": 3
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a duplicated question of: [How to select fields from joined table using TypeORM repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73520301/how-to-select-fields-from-joined-table-using-typeorm-repository)
You can check the answer here. Also this depends on which TypeOrm version you are currently using, as far as I know on version under 0.3 this doesn't work.